# h:outputStylesheet and h:graphicImage not working?

Tags: jsf

I am using h:outputStylesheet and h:graphicImage in my .xhtml files. It works completely fine on my localhost.

Now I tried to upload my .war it on Hosting space provider which uses NGASI AppServer Manager.

Here, h:outputStylesheet and h:graphicImage tags have stopped functioning. What I noticed is that everything with pattern /ctx/faces/javax.faces.resource/....?ln=.... is giving 404: (Not found) error.

For ex:
http://www.edarena.com/EdArena/faces/javax.faces.resource/theme_edarena.css?ln=css
http://www.edarena.com/EdArena/faces/javax.faces.resource/jsf.js?ln=javax.faces&stage=Development
http://www.edarena.com/EdArena/faces/javax.faces.resource/THEME_EDARENA/logo.png?ln=images

All the .xhtml files in app root are getting accessed properly, which means the mapping /faces/* to Faces Servlet is correct in web.xml.

My first impression was that the image or resource path is somehow not getting determined.

But I just tried renaming my file resources/images/THEME_EDARENA/logo.png to logo1.png.

After this when I refresh my pages using this image, I get message 'Unable to find resource THEME_EDARENA/logo.png' in my  tag. If I make it logo.png, the error messages goes away, which means the file is found but something goes wrong while rendering it.

Thanks for any help.

Please suggest something.

BR
Anand

Comment: Odd problem. Try changing `/faces/*` to `*.xhtml` to exclude one and other (this also adds the benefit that you don't need to use any additional path information in URLs).